# Align bootstrap dropdown in input-group to left (underneath the start of the input)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a input group (text input and button with dropdown).  I am having trouble getting my dropdown to align with the text box.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="dropdown open">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
                  type="button" 
                  id="dropdownMenuButton" 
                  data-toggle="dropdown" 
                  aria-haspopup="true" 
                  aria-expanded="false">
                       dropdown
                  </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <ul>
              <li>one</li>
              <li>two</li>
              <li>three</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried `<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">` with no avail.
[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teqy15t7/2/)

What do I need to add to this to align my dropdown menu to the left underneath the start of the input (as if it was a typeahead)?

EDIT: within the dropdown menu is an angular directive, that's likely a relative tool

Comment: Just follow the [docs](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.0/docs/components/#input-groups). Your markup does not conform to the defaults.

Comment: @vanburen this doesn't help me.  I copied this almost directly from a bootstrap doc example.  I do not see anything about aligning the dropdown content to the left of the input on an input-group in these docs.  Perhaps you could point me more specifically?

Comment: Are you saying you just want the dropdown to open under the entire input-group (input plus button) at 100% width instead of it just opening below the button only? If that's not what you're trying to do provide more info.

Comment: @vanburen yes, the dropdown I have here already is built to expand to fit the content (the list items are just being used here as an example) -- there is an angular directive contained within the dropdown that creates a scrollable hierarchy tree

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Quick Fix**

Working Demo **[Here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/XNvNWw?editors=1010)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="testing">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="dropdown open">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <ul>
                <li>one</li>
                <li>two</li>
                <li>three</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.testing {
  position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  dropmenuWidgetPosition();

  function dropmenuWidgetPosition() {
    $('#dropdownMenuButton').dropdown('toggle');
    $(window).on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
      var dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
      var dropMenuDetach = dropdownMenu.detach();

      // detach it and append it to the target

      $(e.target).parents('.input-group').eq(0).find('.testing').append(dropMenuDetach);

      // grab the new offset position

      var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();

      // make sure to place it where it would normally go (this
      // could be
      // improved)

      dropdownMenu.css({
        'display': 'block',
        'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
        'left': 0

      });
    });

    // and when you hide it, reattach the drop down, and hide it
    // normally

    $(window).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
      var dropdownMenu = $(e.target).parents().find('.dropdown-menu');
      var dropMenuDetach = dropdownMenu.detach();
      $(e.target).append(dropMenuDetach);
      dropdownMenu.hide();
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: I really like this answer -- unfortunately I'm using angular and would prefer a solution that uses a bit less grabbing elements and trying to move them